# A tornado chart and p10-p90 in python (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I need to plot the following two things using the Python (matplotlib):

1. A tornado chart (kinda summarizing the sensitivity analysis)
2. And a comparison of mean p10 and p90 values for a list of variety products.

I have never done this before and was trying to use Python (matplotlib). So far no success. Attached what I am/was trying to plot. I drew them by hand as I just thought it might be a lot easier for me to explain visually what I was trying to plot using the Python.

One important thing is that in the tornado chart I would like to see that line that divides on the center of the chart, and on the top are base case numbers (values ranging from 2000 to 5000), and the values for each of my product on the right hand side, respectively. I found some really good looking tornado charts, and those looked really cool, but too lengthy and complicated (lots of funky and cool things in that, and used specifically just for that particular chart).

Comment: You need to post the code you try, and any problems you are having so that we may help you with said issues. See the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your question.

Comment: Do you have a sample of your data to show the format you're starting with? I'm actually about to try to make a tornado chart right now so happy to help.

Comment: Also, a sample of what code you have already and/or links to where you've already looked would be useful too.

Comment: Thanks so much Jamie and Rodin for your willingness to help me!

Comment: See http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/examples/statistics/multiple_histograms_side_by_side.html

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25942703/multiple-side-by-side-histograms-with-matplotlib but don't want to mark it as such as I have one-vote close-as-duplicate on this question.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, matplotlib has no build-in tornado chart function. You will have to roll your own. Here is my attempt at making a plot that resembles your drawing.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

###############################################################################
# The data (change all of this to your actual data, this is just a mockup)
variables = [
    'apple',
    'juice',
    'orange',
    'peach',
    'gum',
    'stones',
    'bags',
    'lamps',
]

base = 3000

lows = np.array([
    base - 246 / 2,
    base - 1633 / 2,
    base - 500 / 2,
    base - 150 / 2,
    base - 35 / 2,
    base - 36 / 2,
    base - 43 / 2,
    base - 37 / 2,
])

values = np.array([
    246,
    1633,
    500,
    150,
    35,
    36,
    43,
    37,
])

###############################################################################
# The actual drawing part

# The y position for each variable
ys = range(len(values))[::-1]  # top to bottom

# Plot the bars, one by one
for y, low, value in zip(ys, lows, values):
    # The width of the 'low' and 'high' pieces
    low_width = base - low
    high_width = low + value - base

    # Each bar is a "broken" horizontal bar chart
    plt.broken_barh(
        [(low, low_width), (base, high_width)],
        (y - 0.4, 0.8),
        facecolors=['white', 'white'],  # Try different colors if you like
        edgecolors=['black', 'black'],
        linewidth=1,
    )

    # Display the value as text. It should be positioned in the center of
    # the 'high' bar, except if there isn't any room there, then it should be
    # next to bar instead.
    x = base + high_width / 2
    if x <= base + 50:
        x = base + high_width + 50
    plt.text(x, y, str(value), va='center', ha='center')

# Draw a vertical line down the middle
plt.axvline(base, color='black')

# Position the x-axis on the top, hide all the other spines (=axis lines)
axes = plt.gca()  # (gca = get current axes)
axes.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
axes.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
axes.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
axes.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')

# Make the y-axis display the variables
plt.yticks(ys, variables)

# Set the portion of the x- and y-axes to show
plt.xlim(base - 1000, base + 1000)
plt.ylim(-1, len(variables))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Jamie and Rodin! I really like the tornado chart. I was also trying to plot a comparison of mean p10 and p90 values for a list of variety products. Basically, I have the same list of products for a comparison of mean of probability being 10% and 90% (i.e. p10-p90). I surfed on the internet a lot and found these samples. Of course, I also tried to change and make my own tornado chart, but it was/is very difficult as each tornado chart was made custom so it was very tricky to change them right away. http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_webagg.html

Comment: I also found this; here some examples, but those are advanced.. http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/tornado-chart-td26614.html

Comment: Rodin, is there a way for me to fill up with a visible color each rectangle and put ticks (tick marks) on the top numbers in that tornado chart? That is exactly what I was trying to make so thanks so much! xxx Sally.

Comment: I also found that some people use overlapped bar chart (not sure if it is called as a tornado chart, but I tried to plot using the same data. Basically, those numbers on the top from 2000 to 5000 would be a base case, and rest of them should sit on the top of the base case bar i.e.: http://peltiertech.com/overlapped-bar-chart-thinner-bars-in-front/  (The very first picture,-- base is a yellow color, and blue rest of the products..)

Comment: Jamie Bull, I will post the sample code later as I do not have this code right now with me on this PC. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I recently needed to make a Tornado chart for some Likert data.

I modified [an example from the gallery](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/horizontal_barchart_distribution.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-horizontal-barchart-distribution-py) to create this:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


category_names = ['Strongly disagree', 'Disagree',
                  'Neither agree nor disagree', 'Agree', 'Strongly agree']
results = {
    'Question 1': [10, 15, 17, 32, 26],
    'Question 2': [26, 22, 29, 10, 13],
    'Question 3': [35, 37, 7, 2, 19],
    'Question 4': [32, 11, 9, 15, 33],
    'Question 5': [21, 29, 5, 5, 40],
    'Question 6': [8, 19, 5, 30, 38]
}


def survey(results, category_names):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    results : dict
        A mapping from question labels to a list of answers per category.
        It is assumed all lists contain the same number of entries and that
        it matches the length of *category_names*. The order is assumed
        to be from 'Strongly disagree' to 'Strongly aisagree'
    category_names : list of str
        The category labels.
    """
    
    labels = list(results.keys())
    data = np.array(list(results.values()))
    data_cum = data.cumsum(axis=1)
    middle_index = data.shape[1]//2
    offsets = data[:, range(middle_index)].sum(axis=1) + data[:, middle_index]/2
    
    # Color Mapping
    category_colors = plt.get_cmap('coolwarm_r')(
        np.linspace(0.15, 0.85, data.shape[1]))
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
    
    # Plot Bars
    for i, (colname, color) in enumerate(zip(category_names, category_colors)):
        widths = data[:, i]
        starts = data_cum[:, i] - widths - offsets
        rects = ax.barh(labels, widths, left=starts, height=0.5,
                        label=colname, color=color)
    
    # Add Zero Reference Line
    ax.axvline(0, linestyle='--', color='black', alpha=.25)
    
    # X Axis
    ax.set_xlim(-90, 90)
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-90, 91, 10))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda x, pos: str(abs(int(x))))
    
    # Y Axis
    ax.invert_yaxis()
    
    # Remove spines
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
    
    # Ledgend
    ax.legend(ncol=len(category_names), bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1),
              loc='lower left', fontsize='small')
    
    # Set Background Color
    fig.set_facecolor('#FFFFFF')

    return fig, ax


fig, ax = survey(results, category_names)
plt.show()
```

[image]