# How to align each set of bar charts in the middle? I am trying to create a tornado chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, seaborn

### The question

My question has nothing to do with the [tornado](https://pypi.org/project/tornado/) package.

I'd like to understand if there is a way to produce tornado charts in Python - I presume using matplotlib and seaborn, but any other package would do.

**The short summary is this**:

- I have a set of bar charts
- say I have 3 variables
- for each of these 3 variables, I am plotting  the impact of a positive change, and that of a negative change
- **The positive and negative bars are not aligned; I need them aligned in the middle**

A tornado chart is a set of bar charts centered in the middle of the screen; the concept is very simple:

- you have a function which calculates an output based on certain inputs
- you vary each of these inputs by a given percentage, say + and -10%
- you calculate by how much the output varies
- you plot the results, ranking from the input with the most impact to the one with the least
- e.g. in the (ugly) picture below, if the price increases by 10%, the output (profit) increases by the amount of the red bar; if the cost increases by 10%, the output decreases by the figure in red

[image]

### What I have done so far

With the code at the bottom, I can produce a bar chart with seaborn; I get the same output with catplot and with barplot; however:

**how can I move the bar so that each set of orange and blue bars is aligned?**

It must be something like setting a negative spacing from one bar to the other, but I can't pass the width argument to the seaborn functions, or I get

```
TypeError: barh() got multiple values for argument 'width'
```

My output is:

[image]

### My code:

**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style='darkgrid')

# creating a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['input'] = ['x','y','z']
df['+']=[100,-50,10]
df['-']=[-80,60,-10]

#now stacking it
df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars ='input', var_name='type of change', value_name='change in the output' )
print(df2)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,2)

sns.catplot(y='input', x='change in the output', hue='type of change',data=df2, kind='bar', \
            orient='h', ax = ax[0])

sns.barplot(y='input', x='change in the output', hue='type of change',data=df2, \
            orient='h', ax= ax[1], width =0.4)
```

EDIT: A comment pointed out this [matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132773/a-tornado-chart-and-p10-p90-in-python-matplotlib) answer. I wasn't familiar with broken_barh and I will look into it. However, I would not count my question as an exact duplicate because:

- the output of that question is so ugly that it's practically unusable, while mine is not beautiful but more useful (at least for my purposes).
- turning that into something less ugly would probably require a lot of work and would mean giving up the convenience of seaborn.

  Plus, you can also see my question as different questions, unrelated to the tornado chart, so they have (I dare think) merit of their own:

  - how do you pass the width argument to seaborn?
  - how do you change the alignment (spacing) of the bars?

Comment: [Here is one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132773/a-tornado-chart-and-p10-p90-in-python-matplotlib) purely in matplotlib, so I don't know if this counts as a duplicate

Comment: @g-anderson , Thank you. I have edited my question to explain why I don't think mine is a duplicate. In summary, my question covers other points not addressed by that link, plus the output of that link is honestly too ugly to be usable, at least for my purposes. It is, however, interesting and I will look into it

Answer (score 2):

This is one way of doing it. The idea is to first split the DataFrame using `groupby`, finding the unique values of types (`+` and `-` in your case) and then plotting them on one common axis object `ax`. For a horizontal bar chart, you want to supply the `height` argument to control the width of the bars.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style='darkgrid')

# creating a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['input'] = ['x','y','z']
df['+']=[100,-50,10]
df['-']=[-80,60,-10]

#now stacking it
df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars ='input', var_name='type of change', value_name='change in the output' )

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for typ, df in zip(df2['type of change'].unique(),df2.groupby('type of change')):
    ax.barh(df[1]['input'], df[1]['change in the output'], height=0.3, label=typ)
ax.legend(title = 'type of change')
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks! But I am not sure I follow 100%. At the first iteration, `typ` will be item 0 of `df2['type of change'].unique()` , i.e. it will be "+".  I would expect `df` to be a groupby object, instead it's a tuple: I am confused!

Comment: Here it is `df[1]` which is the dataframe. I don't know why but I just had to play around to get it working with `[1]`

Comment: Yes, df[0] is '+' and df[1] is the dataframe. I don't understand why: df should be the dataframe only

Comment: This worked for me, but it was confusing. This worked better for me: `for typ, temp in temp2.groupby('type of change'):` and `ax.barh(temp['input'], temp['change in the output'], height=0.3, label=typ)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style='darkgrid')

# creating a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['input'] = ['x','y','z']
df['+']=[100,-50,10]
df['-']=[-80,60,-10]
```

ax = sns.barplot(y='input', x='+', data=df,
orient='h', color ='b', alpha = 1)

ax = sns.barplot(y='input', x='-', data=df,
orient='h', color ='r', alpha = 0.95)

[image]